# How do I open a socket back to port 80 in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, tcp, sockets, policy-server

Is there a way to open a TCP Socket back to a non-standard Silverlight port such as port 80?

I don't quite understand the restrictions on Silverlight ports.

I would like to open a connection back to the server of origin using any port. I can serve a policy file from port 943 if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft restricted the ports to a range well outside the "well known ports."  This prevents Silverlight from communicating directly to most web-based resources like HTTP, POP, SMTP, etc.

The most common way to get around this is to set up a "proxy" service on your domain.  The proxy accepts requests, forwards them through the port on the service you're using, and returns the result.

Comment: Stupid because you can communicate with those services from the browser via a simple XHR anyway... nevermind, its what I expected anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The allowed port range (after the policy server check) is 4502 through 4532 to my knowledge. Using port 80 would be an HttpWebRequest or the like.